# MSBuild switch from x86 to x64 platform based on variable

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

This is the msbuild code

```
<Target Name="_Buildx86x64">
    <MSBuild Projects="SLN.sln" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);DebugSymbols=$(DebugSymbols);DebugType=$(DebugType);Build64=$(Build64)" Targets="ProjectLocation:Rebuild"/>
</Target>
```

This is what I have in the csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Build64)==false">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(Build64)==true">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
<Platforms>x86;x64</Platforms>Build x86 wihtout errors 
<Platforms>x64;x64</Platforms>Build x64 wihtout errors
```

If I have x86 first in the platforms tag Platforms>x86;x64</Platforms running msbuild with Build64 false works, but running it with true gives me this

```
project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net48/win7-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net48' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win7-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.
```

If I do it the other way around x64;x86 Build64 true works but with false it gives me the error above, but instead of x64 it says x86.

Comment: It appears that [PlatformTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-target-framework-and-target-platform?view=vs-2022#target-platform) doesn't accept a list. You can use `x86` or `anycpu32bitpreferred` for your `"'$(Build64)' == 'false'"` condition. (Note the conditions can be on the property - e.g. `<PropertyGroup> <PlatformTarget Condition="'$(Build64)' == 'false'">x86</PlatformTarget> <PlatformTarget Condition="'$(Build64)' == 'true'">x64</PlatformTarget> </PropertyGroup>`)

Comment: The `project.assets.json` error is because you are only doing a `restore` for one of the possible targets. Change your `Targets` to include the `Restore` target.

Comment: I am baffled by a few things here. Why aren't you just building for `AnyCPU`? Why do you need separate 32 and 64 bit builds? Why are you setting `PlatformTarget` instead of `Platform`? (`Platform` will be used to set `PlatformTarget`.) What file contains the `_Buildx86x64` target? Why are you building this file instead of building the `SLN.sln` solution?

Comment: I have edited the the question, I don't have a list in platformtarget, the list is in platforms. I'm building just the project, for testing purposes, building the solution takes 5 min, in the end I will build the entire solution, I get the same error building the solution at the moment. If I build it for anycpu the service starts as 32bits and I get out of memory exceptions, can I build it with anycpu and start it as 64bit?

Comment: `AnyCPU` on a 64 bit capable platform should run as 64 bit. You seem to have gotten yourself into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). See "[Why "Any CPU" application runs on 32bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278974/why-any-cpu-application-runs-on-32bit)"

Comment: I still need a flag to swap between those 2, I need to enable it only on some enviroments to test that nothing breaks and only afterwards enable it everywhere, but this gave me the ideea of putting the flag on prefer32bit, thanks